# global variable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am a newbie to objective c and xcode so please pardon the mistakes in usage of the right technical terms.

I made a new project and have an appdelegate (.h and .m files).
In the app delegate I have some variables (settings). One of the variables is mainImage.
I put it in the appdelegate as I want it to be accessible from any view controller.

I added a viewcontroller called MainViewController (.h and .m files).
In my MainViewController (.m) I have some custom methods.
In the viewDidLoad method I have the following code

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[currentImage setImage:appDelegate.mainImage];
```

Question:

In any of the methods of the MainViewController, whenever I wanted to read the "mainImage" I have to do the above 2 lines.

Is there a place in the .m file that you can do it once and it is available in all the methods of that file?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Prasad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Malloc and @jack...that was pretty close to what I needed..nevertheless, I have quite a few properties..hence I ended including the call in the header file...

```
#define appDelegate ((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

Then I call call appDelegate.any_of_my_properties

From my C# experience, I know that its probably a bad practice to include a global variable in app delegate and reference it this way..however, this one time..I think it makes sense..given that the object is really not tied to any particular view controller (the image was just an example) in reality..I have some dynamic value holders.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method in MainViewController with those two lines it in that returns an object of type `UIImage` or whatever it is, and then just call that. Invocation would be something like `[self mainImage]` and the method signature would be `- (UIImage *)mainImage`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put these two lines in the viewDidLoad method of your `MainViewController` as example:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[currentImage setImage:appDelegate.mainImage];
```

That's done once, then each time you need currentImage content, you just call it:

```
UIImage *img= [[UIImage alloc]init];
img = self.currentImage;
```

Assuming currentImage is declared as property in `MainViewController`.